# When is "use strict" directive checked on build?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, strict

I have an ASP.NET web forms application (using VS2013, targeting .NET4.5).  I've added the `use strict` directive to the top of my `.js` files to enforce Javascript hygiene.

However, I'm having trouble finding documentation of where in the build process `use strict` is enforced.  It doesn't seem like something that would be integrated into `csc.exe`, as it's all about Javascript.  It also appears to be occurring before my post-build events.

Can anyone point me to some documentation this?

---

To clarify, I am not asking for documentation on the Javascript feature, I am asking when the build process for my web application is checking this.  I am getting build errors for violations of "use strict", but I am not sure when in the pipeline this is happening.  Is pre-scanning for strict violations a feature of ASP.NET projects?

[image]

---

**Solution**

I had Microsoft AJAX Minifier enabled on the project, and when I turned it off, I stopped getting the Javascript errors.

Another great reason to use the AJAX Minifier!

http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: `It also appears to be occurring before my post-build events` - what is occurring? "use strict" is a javascript "directive" for the javascript engine - it has no impact on compiling in ASP.NET

Comment: hard to tell I would assume you made a loop declaring i bur forgot to make it var i = 0 instead you made i =0

Comment: What version of Visual studio are you using? It's probably the built in javascript debugging engine

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz, there are multiple for loop errors because there were multiple for loops, each declared like `for(i = 0...` rather than `for(var i = 0...`.  Logically I understand why the errors are there, and I enabled "strict" so that I could see these errors.  I'm just looking for the build tool that is actually notifying me of these errors.

Comment: @Liam, using VS 2013 Professional

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got what you asked for :).

**This answer assumes you want to suppress the errors, not fix them at the current moment**

Now seriously - what you probably need is to stop treating syntax error warnings as errors and start treating them as warnings instead for javascript files (**this will affect all types of syntax errors for javascript files so be cautious**).

The errors you see are caused by IntelliSense going through your files constantly and trying to validate them, not the build itself.

Please try the following in Visual Studio:

1. Go to Tools => Options => Text Editor => JavaScript => IntelliSense
2. Make sure "**Show errors as warning**" under "**Show syntax errors**" is **not checked**.

This way your errors should appear in the Warnings tab.

Comment: I actually like that they are treated as errors, not warnings.  I want to avoid any possible global variable issues.  I found the checkbox in the options menu, but it does not change the error/warning status when I uncheck.  Thanks though, for pointing out the intellisense connection.

Comment: Okay, then maybe you should also look if your project properties has "Threat errors as warnings" with value of "All", cause this will turn back warnings to errors (go figure). I think this is not likely though. I don't recall seeing a project that survives long enough with this option switched on. It gets switched off at some point.